# i am trying to implement Select component from blueprintjs : TypeError: _this.props.itemRenderer is not a function

Tags: reactjs, blueprintjs

```
<Select items={items} filterable={false} itemRenderer={true}>
   <Button rightIcon="caret-down" text="Hello" />
</Select>
```

I initialized items value and i am trying to implement but I am getting an error

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, `itemRenderer` is expected to be a function, not a boolean value. You have set the `itemRenderer` prop to `true`, but it needs to be set to a function that returns a rendered item.

For more help, see [Blueprint's documentation on Select's `itemRenderer`](https://blueprintjs.com/docs/#select/select-component.item-renderer).